# How can I use filters if my TcxGrid is on GridMode True in Delphi

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-2010, tcxgrid

I want to be capable to filter the records loaded in my `TcxGrid` component, I have `GridMode` because the grid is kinda slow to show the records on my application form, but this mode doesn't let me use the filters of the column (just the default ones).

[image]

I found this on the oficial forums:

> Filtering can be implemented by setting the Data Controller's Filter.AutoDataSetFilter property value to True. This way, the filter expression will be automatically applied to the underlying dataset. In the meantime, please note that the Grid working in Grid mode, does not create a list of the possible filter items in the column dropdown filter list. However, you may implement this yourself within the column's OnGetFilterDisplayText or OnGetFilterValues events or the Data Controller's OnGetValueList event. Please refer to the ExpressQuantumGrid's documentation to get more information about these events and how to use them.

But I can't figure out how to do that, since I can't find those documentation. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I suspect this might be so special details, that you really need to contact DevExpress for the documentation. They have a reputation of being very helpful regarding tech support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DevExpress has a great support team, contact them if you need help with their products.

Anyhow, broadly, it works as follows:
You can freely add values by code using the column's `OnGetFilterValues` event:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1MYFIELDGetFilterValues(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; AValueList: TcxDataFilterValueList);
begin
  AValueList.Add(fviValue, 'Value A', 'Value A', False);
  AValueList.Add(fviValue, 'Value B', 'Value B', False);
  AValueList.Add(fviValue, 'Value C', 'Value C', False);
end;
```

[image: Picture showing the filter values dropdown]

Setting the `DataController`'s `Filter.AutoDataSetFilter` causes the underlying `TDataSet.Filter` property to be automatically filled with the corresponding condition. For example:

[image: Picture showing the filter values dropdown with Value A and Value B elements selected]

```
ShowMessage(cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.DataSet.Filter);
```

> ((MYFIELD = 'Value A') OR (MYFIELD = 'Value B'))

It obviously depends on how the `TDataSet`'s descendant class you're using reacts when the `Filter`'s property changes.

If you need more flexibility, you can use the `DataController.Filter.OnBeforeChange` or the `DataController.Filter.OnChanged` event handlers.